# How to handle the chained Except?

Tags: haskell

I have a question about chained `Control.Monad.Except`. To make the question clear, consider the following example:

Firstly, we define the errors as below:

```
import Control.Monad.Except
import Prelude hiding (lex)

data BufError   = BufClosedError      deriving Show
data LexError   = NoSuchTokenError    deriving Show
data ParseError = MismatchSymbolError deriving Show
```

the `BufError` come from reading buffer

```
readBuf::Except BufError a
readBuf = throwError BufClosedError
```

and when it occurs, such error embedded in the exception of `lex`

```
lex::ExceptT LexError (Except BufError) a
lex = lift $ readBuf
```

and a parser can handle any sources and lift the errors occurred from the source to `ExceptT ParseError m a`:

```
parse::Monad m=>m a->ExceptT ParseError m a
parse source = lift source
```

and now, when run the parser with different source, it need different handlers to extract the result from the `ExceptT` as

```
handleError3 = runExceptT . runExceptT . runExceptT
handleError2 = runExceptT . runExceptT

runParse3 = handleError3 $ parse lex
runParse2 = handleError2 $ parse readBuf
```

The question is how to combine `handleError3` and `handleError2` to one generic function `handlerError` such that we can handle `parse lex` and `parse readBuf` with single function as:

```
runParse = handlerError . parse

runParse lex
runParse readBuf
```

Furthermore, If the chained `ExceptT` with "variable length" such as

```
ExceptT e1 (ExceptT e2 (....(Except e'))) a
```

Is it possible to define a function to handle it as

```
handler = runExceptT . runExceptT ... . runExceptT
```

with correct number of `runExceptT` corresponding to each `ExceptT`?

Comment: Is there some problem with a closed set of errors such as `data Error = BufClosedError | NoSuchTokenError | MismatchSymbolError deriving (Show)`?  Then you could use `Except Error a` instead of stacks of ExceptT transformers.

Comment: I would look at https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/11/03/trouble_with_typed_errors.html as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pragmatic Answer**

> Firstly, we define the errors as below:

You are starting off poorly.  If you want to simply catch all errors and have a closed set of error constructors then use a single type:

```
data Error = BufClosedError | NoSuchTokenError | MismatchSymbolError
    deriving (Show)
```

In this manner you can use a single monad stack and a single type for your catch routine:

```
readBuf::Except Error a
readBuf = throwError BufClosedError

lex::Except Error a
lex = readBuf

handleError3 = runExcept
handleError2 = runExcept
... etc...
```

**Academic Answer**

If you do not have a closed set of error types or do not wish to create a single type that encompasses all errors then you can borrow from [Data types a la carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7EW.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf).  In that paper we see how to define fixed-points of data declarations so they can be expanded.  Read the paper.  Work through it.  As a teaser consider:

First we need a fixed point of data.  This is often called `data Fix = In ...` but for your uses we should probably call it `Error`:

```
data Error f = Error (f (Error f))
```

This is the heart of everything that will follow, don't brush it aside.  What we have here is the ability to parameterize your errors with any error value from the rest of your system.  We should now define your errors not as plan singletons, as shown in the question, but as data types that accept this `f` parameter:

```
data BufErrorTy f = BufCloseError deriving (Show)
data LexErrorTy f = LexErrorTy deriving (Show)
data ParseErrorTy f = ParseErrorTy deriving (Show)
```

We can now add polymorphic types that allow us to talk about buffer, lexer, and parse errors in the context of any stack of errors:

```
bufCloseError :: (BufErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
bufCloseError = inject BufCloseError
lexError :: (LexErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
lexError = inject LexErrorTy
parseError :: (ParseErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
parseError = inject ParseErrorTy
```

Wait, what?  We just said `BufErrorTy :<: e` and did an `inject` of a buffer error.  What's that about?

Well we want to be able to use buffer errors, such as BufCloseError, any time the buffer error is one of a set of possible errors right?  So we defined a way to inject and recover buffer errors:

```
class (sub :<: sup) where
    inj :: sub a -> sup a
    rec :: sup a -> Maybe (sub a)

instance f :<: f where
    inj = id
    rec = Just . id
```

Cool, but how do we build sets of allowed errors?

```
data (f :+: g) e = Inl (f e) | Inr (g e)
```

That's a lot like `Either` except with an extra `e` parameter.  We have a set of errors where the actual error is the left one (`f e`) or the right one (`g e`).

There's still a need to say how we inject and recover errors on this stack so let's write those instances:

```
instance f :<: (f :+: g) where
    inj = Inl
    rec (Inl f) = Just f
    rec _ = Nothing
instance (f :<: g) => f :<: (h :+: g) where
    inj = Inr . inj
    rec (Inr hg) = rec hg
    rec _ = Nothing
```

Wow, that's been a lot of machinery.  But now we can finally use it all to do things like throw an error while limiting the type signature to only allowing buffer errors:

```
readBuf :: (BufErrorTy :<: e) => Except (Error e) a
readBuf = throwError bufCloseError
```

And without any explicit `lift`ing of functions we can call this routine from another function that can throw more than just buffer errors:

```
lex :: Except (Error (LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy)) a
lex = readBuf
```

And certainly we can keep building on this, such as throwing different errors with large and hairy sets of possible errors thrown by the context.  Notice that it all type checks so long as the error we throw is one of the types listed in the `Except e` set of errors that might appear:

```
parse2 :: Except (Error (ParseErrorTy :+: LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy :+: FooTy)) a
parse2 = throwError parseError
```

This can all be caught using function designed to catch only the exact error desired by recovering the desired error and ignoring errors of other types:

```
catchSome ::
    (s :<: t)
     => Except (Error t) a
     -> (s (Error t) -> Except (s (Error t)) a)
     -> Except (Error t) a
catchSome op c =
    catchError op (\orig ->
        case recover orig of
            Just e -> withExcept inject (c e)
            Nothing -> throwError orig)
```

And testing can be quite fun:

```
> case runExcept $ \
    catchSome (Main.lex >> pure "no error") (\BufCloseError -> pure "caught") of {
      Right r -> print r ;
      Left e -> print "Uncaught error }
"caught"
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Control.Monad.Except

data (f :+: g) e = Inl (f e) | Inr (g e)

infixr 6 :+:

class (sub :<: sup) where
    inj :: sub a -> sup a
    rec :: sup a -> Maybe (sub a)

instance f :<: f where
    inj = id
    rec = Just . id

instance f :<: (f :+: g) where
    inj = Inl
    rec (Inl f) = Just f
    rec _ = Nothing

instance (f :<: g) => f :<: (h :+: g) where
    inj = Inr . inj
    rec (Inr hg) = rec hg
    rec _ = Nothing

inject :: (s :<: t) => s (Error t) -> Error t
inject = Error . inj

recover :: (s :<: t) => Error t -> Maybe (s (Error t))
recover (Error x) =
    case rec x of
        Just e -> Just e
        Nothing -> Nothing

data FooTy f = FooTy deriving (Show)
data BufErrorTy f = BufCloseError deriving (Show)
data LexErrorTy f = LexErrorTy deriving (Show)
data ParseErrorTy f = ParseErrorTy deriving (Show)

data Error f = Error (f (Error f))

bufCloseError :: (BufErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
bufCloseError = inject BufCloseError
lexError :: (LexErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
lexError = inject LexErrorTy
parseError :: (ParseErrorTy :<: e) => Error e
parseError = inject ParseErrorTy

fooError :: (FooTy :<: e) => Error e
fooError = inject FooTy

readBuf :: (BufErrorTy :<: e) => Except (Error e) a
readBuf = throwError bufCloseError

lex :: Except (Error (LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy)) a
lex = readBuf

parse1 :: Except (Error (ParseErrorTy :+: LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy)) a
parse1 = throwError bufCloseError

parse2 :: Except (Error (ParseErrorTy :+: LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy :+: FooTy)) a
parse2 = throwError parseError

foo :: Except (Error (LexErrorTy :+: BufErrorTy :+: FooTy)) a
foo = throwError fooError

catchSome ::
    (s :<: t)
    => Except (Error t) a
    -> (s (Error t) -> Except (s (Error t)) a)
    -> Except (Error t) a
catchSome op c =
    catchError
        op
        (\orig ->
            case recover orig of
                Just e -> withExcept inject (c e)
                Nothing -> throwError orig)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let onlyBufError :: BufErrorTy s -> Except t ()
        onlyBufError BufCloseError = pure ()
    let nestedBufError :: BufErrorTy :<: t => BufErrorTy (Error t) -> Except (BufErrorTy (Error t)) ()
        nestedBufError BufCloseError = pure ()
    let nestedParseError :: ParseErrorTy :<: t => ParseErrorTy (Error t) -> Except (ParseErrorTy (Error t)) ()
        nestedParseError _ = pure ()
    case runExcept $ catchSome Main.lex onlyBufError of
        Left _e -> putStrLn "Uncaught (failure)"
        Right () -> putStrLn "Caught (success)"
    case runExcept $ catchSome Main.parse2 onlyBufError of
        Left _e -> putStrLn "Uncaught (success)"
        Right () -> putStrLn "Caught (failure)"
    case runExcept $ catchSome Main.parse1 nestedBufError of
        Left _e -> putStrLn "Uncaught (failure)"
        Right () -> putStrLn "Caught (success)"
    case runExcept $ catchSome Main.parse2 nestedParseError of
        Left _e -> putStrLn "Uncaught (failure)"
        Right () -> putStrLn "Caught (success)"
    case runExcept $ catchSome Main.foo nestedBufError of
        Left _e -> putStrLn "Uncaught (success)"
        Right () -> putStrLn "Caught (failure)"
```